# How to fix CSS for pickList in JSF primefaces 3.3

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

When I using pickList of primefaces I had a problem:

This is my pickList:

```
<p:pickList id="pkList" value="#{func_route.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" filterMatchMode="contains"  showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" />
```

This is my CSS for my pickList:

```
.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

But CSS of primefaces:

```
.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list {
    width: 350px !important;
}
```

So attribute width of my CSS are not accept in this my code.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override those classes defined in primefaces.css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css)

Comment: Sorry but it not works for me, because in there Attribute width of primefaces was fixed !important, so I can't override it, other attributes I still override normarly!

Comment: Apparently your CSS is not loaded after PrimeFaces one. Either fix the loading order or add a custom class.

Comment: yes, so how can I change order of loading ?

Comment: I tried as solution link you suggested but it not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Just override its css in your own css file:

```css
.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list {
    width: 100px;
}
```